# How to create different button based on a condition?

Tags: php, button

How do I create a button based on the status. Let's say if I'm not logged in login, the button will direct to the login page, if not, the button will direct to the logout page. Can anyone tell me how to do this in `PHP`? This is my attempt:

```
$LoginStatus = False;

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['LoginName'])){
  $LoginStatus = True;  
} else {
  $loginname = "Guest";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$LoginStatus = False;

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['LoginName'])) { ?>
  <a class="button" href="logout/path">Logout</a>
<?php 
} else { ?>

  <a class="button" href="login/path">Logout</a>
<?php } ?>
```

In this case you use an `<a>` tag, but if you want to use a regular button you can do it with javascript or with a form.

Comment: since you gave the <a> a class called "button" it would be ideal just to style it as a button. No need for javascript.

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal. I was mentioning Javascript in the case he preferred to use a regular `<button>` or `<input>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use Form.

```
<form method="get" action="userActions.php">    
<?php
$LoginStatus = False;

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['LoginName'])) { ?>
  <button type="submit" name="logout">Logout</button>
<?php 
} else { ?>

  <button type="submit" name="login">Login</button>
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could simplify your code by doing something like:

```
<?php
session_start();
$name = isset($_SESSION['LoginName']) ? "logout" : "login";
?>
<form method="get" action="userActions.php">    
  <button type="submit" name="<?php echo($name); ?>"><?php echo(ucfirst($name)); ?></button>
</form>
```